# Flutter web - Upload video in Firebase storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

How to upload a video to Firebase Storage with Flutter Web ?

I have a video in mp4 format on my computer.

I am in Flutter 3.7.1, the storage package is in 11.0.11

Do you have an idea? A solution?

When I use the method :

```
 snapshot = await reference.putFile(file);
```

I get the following error that is caught:
Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem

My file have a path which looks like this:
blob:http://localhost:7800/id

When my file is just an image, for the web, I use :

```
        snapshot = await reference.putData(await file.readAsBytes(), metadata);
```

When i try :

```
snapshot = await reference.putString(file.path);
```

Firebase does save a file, but it only represents a black image, the video is not actually stored on Firebase Storage

Comment: Generally speaking, when I have issues with files in code it's an issue with getting the actual file object it's self. Meaning you should use a package like  [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to get your file object then send it to firebase.

Comment: @returnVoid
I tried with the file_picker package 

But for the video, if I try to see what's in 

file.bytes

my web page freezes and crashes, in console I have : 

Debugger: Target crashed!


even if it is included in a try/catch